# Python - How to avoid discrepancy of base y**log base y of x, in gmpy2

Tags: python, logarithm, gmpy

The Following code examples my problem which does not occur between 10 power 10 and 10 power 11, but does for the example given in code and above it.

I can't see where in my code I am not properly handling  the retrieval of the original value. May be I have just missed something simple.

I need to be sure that I can recover `x` from `log x` for various bases. Rather than rely on a library function such as `gmpy2`, is there any reverse **anti-log** algorithm which guarantees that for say `2**log2(x)` it will give `x`.

I can see how to directly develop a log, but not how to get back, eg, Taylor series needs a lot of terms... [How can I write a power function myself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882706/how-can-i-write-a-power-function-myself) and @dan04 reply. Code follows.

```
from gmpy2 import gcd, floor, next_prime, is_prime    
from gmpy2 import factorial, sqrt, exp, log,log2,log10,exp2,exp10    
from gmpy2 import mpz, mpq, mpfr, mpc, f_mod, c_mod,lgamma    
from time import clock    
import random    
from decimal import getcontext
x=getcontext().prec=1000 #also tried 56, 28
print(getcontext())

def rint():#check accuracy of exp(log(x))
    e=exp(1)
    l2=log(2)
    l10=log(10)
    #x=random.randint(10**20,10**21) --replaced with an actual value on next line
    x=481945878080003762113
    # logs to different bases
    x2=log2(x)
    x10=log10(x)
    xe=log(x)
    # logs back to base e
    x2e=xe/l2
    x10e=xe/l10
    #
    e2=round(2**x2)
    e10=round(10**x10)
    ex=round(e**xe)
    #
    ex2e=round(2**x2e)
    ex10e=round(10**x10e)
    error=5*x-(e2+e10+ex+ex2e+ex10e)
    print(x,"error sum",error)
    #print(x,x2,x10,xe)
    #print(x2e,x10e)
    print(e2,e10,ex)
    print(ex2e,ex10e)
 rint()
```

Comment: First, I don't know how you got `random.randint` to work with these limits. It doesn't on my machine... But anyway I suspect this is related to float arithmetic accuracy.

Comment: I think you are right, in which case my question is, how do i get round that, either in python or gmpy2 or some other library?

Comment: I can get the anti-log by method described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring, so for log 2 it is a matter of not going via natural log, but directly computing log base 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I maintain the `gmpy2` library.*

In your example, you are using `getcontext()` from the `decimal` module. You are not changing the precision used by `gmpy2`. Since the default precision of `gmpy2` is 53 bits and your value of x requires 69 bits, it is expected that you have an error.

Here is a corrected version of your example that illustrates how the accumulated error changes as you increase the precision.

```
import gmpy2

def rint(n):
    gmpy2.get_context().precision = n
    # check accuracy of exp(log(x))
    e = gmpy2.exp(1)
    l2 = gmpy2.log(2)
    l10 = gmpy2.log(10)
    x = 481945878080003762113
    # logs to different bases
    x2 = gmpy2.log2(x)
    x10 = gmpy2.log10(x)
    xe = gmpy2.log(x)
    # logs back to base e
    x2e = xe/l2
    x10e = xe/l10
    #
    e2 = round(2**x2)
    e10 = round(10**x10)
    ex = round(e**xe)
    #
    ex2e = round(2**x2e)
    ex10e = round(10**x10e)
    error = 5 * x - (e2 + e10 + ex + ex2e + ex10e)
    print("precision", n, "value", x, "error sum", error)

for n in range(65, 81):
    rint(n)
```

And here are the results.

```
precision 65 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 1061
precision 66 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 525
precision 67 value 481945878080003762113 error sum -219
precision 68 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 181
precision 69 value 481945878080003762113 error sum -79
precision 70 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 50
precision 71 value 481945878080003762113 error sum -15
precision 72 value 481945878080003762113 error sum -14
precision 73 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 0
precision 74 value 481945878080003762113 error sum -2
precision 75 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 1
precision 76 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 0
precision 77 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 0
precision 78 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 0
precision 79 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 0
precision 80 value 481945878080003762113 error sum 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you set the decimal module accuracy, the usual suggestion is to use Decimal datatype

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 1000

# Just a different method to get the random number:
x = Decimal(round(10**20 * (1 + 9 * random.random()))) 

x10 = Decimal.log10(x)
e10 = 10**x10

e10 - x
#outputs: Decimal('5.2E-978')
```

For different bases you may want to use the logarithmic formula:

```
x2 = Decimal.log10(x) / Decimal.log10(Decimal('2'))
e2 = 2**x2

e2 - x
#outputs: Decimal('3.9E-978')
```

Comment: OK, thanks, this works for Decimal, log10, but what works in general for "various bases", ie different bases, any integer base other than natural log, eg 2, to recover x?

Comment: @ocopa - see my edit regarding different bases. Just use log10(x)/log10(base).

Comment: Yes, i knew that but i was trying to work out why i was getting the wrong answer from gmpy2, and what was the underlying code. It seems gmpy2 is using log base e behind the scene or maybe there is a float accuracy issue as we thought.  i will  mark this as answered after i post a couple of useful references, shortly.

Comment: Useful Logarithm references
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm
answer by Dan04 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2882706/how-can-i-write-a-power-function-myself
answer by log0 at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719631/log-to-the-base-2-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Aguy solved my problem, as acknowledged.
I had not taken account of needing more than 15 digits of precision.
This answer to another question covers that ground.
[gmpy2 log2 not accurate after 16 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059198/gmpy2-log2-not-accurate-after-16-digits)